# matlab image popping during animation creation

Tags: matlab, animation

I'll do my best to explain my problem. I am simulating the dynamics of a network and I'd like to get an animation where each frame represents my network with a specific color for each node with respect to an input file. 
Here my script

```
 for ii=1:Movie_size

hfig=figure('visible','off');
hold on;

%plot edges
    for kk=1:Nedge,
        plot(xedge(kk,:),yedge(kk,:),'black')
    end

%color of the nodes
    for kk=1:nodes,
        val=(1-(Color_node(12798 ,kk)-umin)/(umax-umin));
        ggCol(kk,:)=[1,val,1-val];
    end

%enhanced the contrast of the figure
    ggCol = imadjust(ggCol,[.2 .3 0; .6 .7 1],[]);

%plot nodes
    for kk=1:nodes,
        plot(xpos(kk),ypos(kk),'o','MarkerFaceColor',ggCol(kk,:), ...
            'MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerSize',10)
    end

    frames(ii)=getframe(hfig);

    hold off;

end

movie(frames);
```

I succeeded in plotting each frame but when I want to get the animation, I have all the figures being displayed and no movie. I tried a lot of different things but it never works...

PS : I have been editing the title since the topic seems to have been already asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have already called `getframe` which takes a screen capture of the current figure, you need to *do something with this frame* to make a movie. The typical thing would be to add this frame to an existing [`VideoWriter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) object within your loop.

```
writer = VideoWriter('output.avi');

hfig = figure();
hplot = plot(rand(10,1));

for k = 1:100
    % Update the plot
    set(hplot, 'YData', rand(10, 1));

    % Take a screengrab and add it to the video file
    frame = getframe(hfig);
    writer.writeVideo(frame);
end

writer.close()
```

Alternately, you can create an *array* of frames and then display these interactively within MATLAB with [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html).

```
for k = 1:100
    frames(k) = getframe(hfig);
end

% View as a movie
movie(frames)
```

**Update**

Based on your updated question, the windows *have* to popup because `getframe` must have the figure render before it is able to capture the screen. Also, you've created your array of frames but haven't attempted to display a movie. You need:

```
movie(frames)
```

Comment: Sorry for answering with such delay, I was absent. I have been trying to do your way but I still get a lot errors. I think I do not manage really well with the loops, etc... Could you be a bit more specific in your example using pieces of my script ? Thanks and sorry again

Comment: @Hyppolite Post the code you've tried and I can provide some feedback.

Comment: Since it has been pointed out as a duplicate I changed the title. With the script I now have I get the movie but my problem is that the figure are continuously popping during the execution of my script...

Comment: @Hyppolite That is a completely different question...I have updated with a brief explanation of why that's happening. Also you've created your `frames` array but you never display it.

Comment: You're right I forgot to add it at the end but I was doing it on the terminal and it is working, I now just have to enhance a bit my movie and to find a way to export it properly. Also, just in order to know if that is possible, can I use a vector containing each time between two successive frame ? My data come from a stochastic simulation and the sampling time is not regular. Otherwise thanks for everything you have been really helpfull !

Comment: @Hyppolite To "export" it you want to use the `VideoWriter` piece that I have included above to export it frame by frame to a movie file. Also it is not possible to do variable frame rates